# Memcpy causing segfault when copying struct arrays

Tags: c

I'm trying to make a rehashing function that will work on very large hash tables (with more than 1 million entries) and my current method is very inefficient. Here are my structures

```
typedef struct {
   int id, count, correct, valid;
   char* word;
} Entry;

typedef struct {
   Entry* arr;
   int size, numValid;
} Hash;
```

Here is how it functions now (very slowly, not using memcpy):

```
void rehash(Hash* hash) {
   Entry* tempArr;
   int i;

   tempArr = calloc(hash->size, sizeof(Entry));
   for(i = 0; i < hash->size; i++) {
      if(hash->arr[i].count) {
         tempArr[i].count = hash->arr[i].count;
         tempArr[i].correct = hash->arr[i].valid;
         tempArr[i].word = malloc(strlen(hash->arr[i].word) + 1);
         strcpy(tempArr[i].word,hash->arr[i].word);
         tempLen++;
      }
      memcpy(&tempArr[i],&hash->arr[i],sizeof(Entry));
      tempArr[i] = hash->arr[i];
   }

   removeAllEntries(hash);
   resize(hash);


   for(i = 0; i < (hash->size / 2); i++) {
      if(tempArr[i].count > 0) {
         addEntry(hash,tempArr[i].word,tempArr[i].count);
         /*printf("Added %s with count %d\n",tempArr[i].word,tempArr[i].count);*/
        free(tempArr[i].word);
      }
   }
   free(tempArr);
}
```

I'd prefer to use memcpy, but I can't for the life of me get it to work correctly. Here's what I'm trying (this is the code that doesn't work, and what I'm looking for help with):

```
void rehash(Hash* hash) {
   Entry* tempArr;
   int i;

   tempArr = calloc(hash->size, sizeof(Entry));

   fprintf(stderr,"size: %d\n",hash->size * sizeof(Entry));
   memcpy((tempArr),(hash->arr),hash->size * sizeof(Entry));

   removeAllEntries(hash);
   resize(hash);

  for(i = 0; i < (hash->size / 2); i++) {
     if(tempArr[i].count > 0) {
        addEntry(hash,tempArr[i].word,tempArr[i].count);
        /*printf("Added %s with count %d\n",tempArr[i].word,tempArr[i].count);*/
        free(tempArr[i].word);
     }
   }
   free(tempArr);
}
```

I'm sure it's an easy, one-line fix, but I just can't get myself to see it.

```
void addEntry(Hash* hash, char* tag, int count) {
   int value = CHV(hash->size, tag), flag = 1, iter = 0;
   int possIndex = findEntry(hash, tag);
   /*fprintf(stderr,"AddEntry...\n");*/


   if(possIndex >= 0) {
      (hash->arr[possIndex].count)++;
      return;
   }



   if((hash->size - hash->numValid) < ((double)hash->size / 10))
   {
      rehash(hash);
   }
   while(flag) {
      iter++;
      if(!(hash->arr[value].valid)) {
         hash->arr[value].word = calloc(strlen(tag) + 1, sizeof(char));
         strcpy(hash->arr[value].word, tag);
         wordsAlloced++;
         hash->arr[value].valid = 1;
         hash->arr[value].correct = 1;
         hash->arr[value].count = count;
         flag = 0;
      }
      else {
         value++;
         if(value == hash->size) {
            value = 0;
         }
      }
   }
   hash->numValid++;
}
```

Comment: Would be handy to know the declarations of `Entry` and `Hash`

Comment: Which snippet do you have issues with? Which one are you using. To which your question refers?

Comment: You want to show us the definition of `Entry`.

Comment: Added definitions for Entry and Hash

Comment: Check return value of `calloc`.

Comment: It appears to be returning a valid pointer

Comment: added addEntry to the question

Comment: I think that `memcpy` is no problem. problem is free all Entry by `removeAllEntries(hash);` then  `tempArr[i].word` is the double free in `free(tempArr[i].word);`  Because it's copied pointer. Also Using `tempArr[i].word` in `addEntry(hash,tempArr[i].word,tempArr[i].count);` is invalid. It's already free'd.

Comment: I propose, process of resizing  to do by `realloc`.

Comment: `memcpy(&tempArr[i],&hash->arr[i],sizeof(Entry));`  overwrites/redoes all assignments that have been done inside the `if(){}` block, including the mallocced string, which is thus leaked by the memcpy(). and `tempArr[i] = hash->arr[i];` redoes these assignments one more time, just to be sure.

Comment: @wildplasser yes. But I think it is probably the code should be a test or else block. It does not exist in [the previous code](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/36951318/free-segfault-in-hash-table-rehash). OP's questions is the second of the code  .

Comment: I stopped reading after that. OP probably does a *deep* free() on the old array afterwards.

Answer (score 1):

I think that memcpy is no problem. problem is free all Entry by `removeAllEntries(hash);` then `tempArr[i].word` is the double `free` in `free(tempArr[i].word);` Because it's copied pointer. Also Using `tempArr[i].word` in `addEntry(hash,tempArr[i].word,tempArr[i].count);` is invalid. It's already `free`'d.

---

One solution proposes the use of `realloc`.

replace

```
void resize(Hash* hash) {
    free(hash->arr);
    hash->size *= 2;
    hash->arr = calloc(hash->size, sizeof(Entry)); 
    //TOTALALLOC += (hash->size * sizeof(Entry));
}
```

with

```
void resize(Hash* hash) {
    Entry* tempArr;

    if((tempArr = realloc(hash->arr, 2 * hash->size * sizeof(Entry)))==NULL){
        fprintf(stderr,"failed realloc in resize.\n");
        return ;
    }
    hash->size *= 2;
    hash->arr = tempArr;
    //TOTALALLOC += (hash->size * sizeof(Entry));
}
```

Does not rehash for resizing purpose.

---

Another solution

If rehashing is necessary for some reason. to change in the following

```
void rehash(Hash* hash) {
    Entry* tempArr;
    int i;

    tempArr = malloc(hash->size * sizeof(Entry));//Initialization isn't required because it is replaced by memcpy.

    //fprintf(stderr,"size: %d\n",hash->size * sizeof(Entry));
    memcpy(tempArr,hash->arr, hash->size * sizeof(Entry));
    //To replicate word
    for(i = 0; i < hash->size; i++) {
        if(hash->arr[i].count) {
            tempArr[i].word = malloc(strlen(hash->arr[i].word) + 1);
            strcpy(tempArr[i].word, hash->arr[i].word);
        }
    }
    removeAllEntries(hash);
    resize(hash);

    for(i = 0; i < (hash->size / 2); i++) {
        if(tempArr[i].count > 0) {
            addEntry(hash,tempArr[i].word, tempArr[i].count);
            /*printf("Added %s with count %d\n",tempArr[i].word,tempArr[i].count);*/
            free(tempArr[i].word);
        }
    }
    free(tempArr);
}
```

If `numValid` is the represent the valid registration number, I think that it is sufficient to save only a `word` and `count`.

Comment: That works, and definitely seems a bit faster. The problem is that rehashing with large hash sizes still takes enormous amounts of time, one rehash taking 5 minutes in later cases. How can I limit this?

Comment: @EvanCooper When you try to improve in this part, again I think that whether to process only the `word` and `count` (Untested). I think that some time is inevitable What is needed is a large amount of data rehash.